# Why is my code running so slow?

Tags: led, multiplexer, pwm

Hey guys. I'm building a 9 RGB LED chaser, using an ATTiny2313 to drive it. The cathodes are connected to all of PORTB and pin 6 of PORTD. I wrote some code to drive them all, but for some reason it's really slow. If red is set to 200 and blue to 100, you can see the red staying on for twice the amount of time, and you can almost time it. This should be happening many, many times a second but it's going very slow.

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>    // Defines pins, ports, etc to make programs easier to read
#define F_CPU 1000000UL       // Sets up the default speed for delay.h
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define bit_get(p,m) ((p) & (m))
#define bit_set(p,m) ((p) |= (m))
#define bit_clear(p,m) ((p) &= ~(m))
#define bit_flip(p,m) ((p) ^= (m))
#define bit_write(c,p,m) (c ? bit_set(p,m) : bit_clear(p,m))
#define BIT(x) (0x01 << (x))
#define LONGBIT(x) ((unsigned long)0x00000001 << (x)) 

#define RED 1
#define BLUE 0
#define GREEN 2


void delay_ms(uint16_t ms) {
  while ( ms ){
    _delay_ms(1);
    ms--;
  }
}
struct LED {
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t g;
    uint8_t b;
};

volatile struct LED strip[9];
uint8_t x;
uint8_t y;

int main(void)
{
DDRD = 0xFF;
DDRB = 0xFF;
for(x = 0; x <= 8; x++){
    strip[x].r = 0;
    strip[x].g = 0;
    strip[x].b = 255;
}
while(1){
    PORTB = 0xFF;
    PORTD = (1 << 6);
    for(x = 0; x <= 255; x++){
        for(y = 0; y <= 8; y++){

            if(strip[y].r > x)
                bit_set(PORTD, BIT(RED));
            else
                bit_clear(PORTD, BIT(RED));
            if(strip[y].g > x)
                bit_set(PORTD, BIT(GREEN));
            else
                bit_clear(PORTD, BIT(GREEN));
            if(strip[y].b > x)
                bit_set(PORTD, BIT(BLUE));
            else
                bit_clear(PORTD, BIT(BLUE));    

            _delay_us(1);
            if(y == 0){
                bit_clear(PORTD, BIT(6));
                PORTB = 0xFF;
            }else{
                bit_clear(PORTB, BIT(y-1));
                bit_set(PORTD, BIT(6));
            }
            _delay_us(10);
            PORTB = 0xFF;
            PORTD |= (1 << 6);
            _delay_us(1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Do the math how many cycles this uses:

255 * 9 * ca 100 cycles per iteration / 1 MHz = ca 0.25s

where the 100 is a very rough ballpark estimate, it could easily be more depending on the implementation of delay_us.

I'd increase the clock frequency and use an interrupt-driven approach.

But it's still going to be hard to do do proper dimming when you also do multiplexing, you'll be limited to a few colors to avoid too much flickering.

Answer (score 1):

Did you reprogram the CLK8DIV fuse from its default setting? The factory setting divides the clock frequency by 8. 
It is possible  to do fast PWM dimming of a reasonable number of LEDs on AVR but the code needs to be very carefully written.

Comment: The clock is at the default, 8MHz divided by 8 to make 1 MHz.